# How to set a configuration parameter in config.yml in Symfony without creating a service

Tags: php, symfony, ssl, heroku

I am using Heroku to host my Symfony 3 application. I am going to switch to a new database provider that requires me to set custom certificates.

I don't want to store the certificates under version control, so I decided to write a new command that downloads the certificate files on deployment from a URL that is set as an environment variable.

To read environment variables I use `incenteev-parameters` in `composer.json`, this then sets the appropriate values at `parameters.yml`. However as far as I know there is no way to read this value directly from `parameters.yml`, so I have to have something in `config.yml` that uses my new url parameter at `parameters.yml`, but this would require me to create a new service.

I simply want to read this new url parameter from my new command so that I can download my certificates on deployment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend your command from [ContainerAwareCommand class](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html#getting-services-from-the-service-container) and access your parameter from parameters.yml using the following way:

```
$this->getContainer()->getParameter('your_parameter_key');
```

Or you can [define your command as a service](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/commands_as_services.html) and inject required parameters.

Comment: That only works if the parameter has already been defined as a service, but defining the command as a service might work. I will try that and get back to you.

Comment: You cannot define a parameter as a service. You should define your parameter value in parameters.yml and get it from your command class using one of suggested ways from my answer. Please take a look at Symfony documentation about parameters: http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parameters.html

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean define a parameter as service. What I meant is that you need to define a service that uses a given parameter. `$this->getContainer()->getParameter('your_parameter_key');` only works for parameters that are used by a given service. It is not possible to directly access something on `parameters.yml` with `$this->getContainer()->getParameter('your_parameter_key');` unless there is some service using that parameter in `config.yml`. I used your second suggestion and it worked.